# SQL Recursion: Obtain all possible relationships between parents and descendants

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I would like to run a recursive CTE so that I can obtain Table 2, using the information provided in Table 1.

Table 1:

```
Employee  | ReportsTo
a           NULL
b           a
c           b
d           c
```

Table 2:

```
Employee  | ReportsTo  | depth
a           NULL         0
b           a            1
c           a            2
d           a            3
c           b            1
d           b            2
d           c            1
```

So far, I have:

```
with cte
    (Employee
    ,ReportsTo
    ,depth)
as
    (
    select  Employee
            ,ReportsTo
            ,0 as depth
    from    [Table 1]
    where   ReportsTo is null

    UNION ALL

    select  a.Employee
            ,a.ReportsTo
            ,b.depth + 1
    from    cte b
    join [Table 1] a    
            on a.ReportsTo = b.Employee
    )

select  *
from    cte
order by depth
```

which returns:

```
Employee  | ReportsTo | Depth
a           NULL        0
b           a           1
c           b           2
d           c           3
```

To give a couple examples to illustrate my question, note that I am missing the relationship between Employee "d" indirectly reporting to Employee "b". Or Employee "d" indirectly reporting to Employee "a".

Comment: @Amit I don't think the answer in the link provides exactly what I am looking for. I am wanting to achieve the results in Table 2, rather than specifying the value of the Employee or ReportsTo through a WHERE clause. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  You needed to remove the `where ReportsTo is null` from your cte in order to get all of the nodes on the branches.  (I also added a concat so you can see the full Tree Path and all nodes in between the top node and the employee.)

```
WITH cte
    (TopNode
    ,Employee
    ,ReportsTo
    ,Depth
    ,TreePath)
AS
    (
    SELECT ReportsTo AS TopNode
           ,Employee
           ,ReportsTo
           ,0 AS Depth
           ,CAST(ReportsTo AS VARCHAR(max)) AS TreePath
    FROM   #tblTable1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.TopNode
           ,a.Employee
           ,a.ReportsTo
           ,cte.Depth + 1 AS depth
           ,CAST(cte.TreePath + ' -> ' +
            CAST(a.ReportsTo AS VARCHAR(max)) 
            AS VARCHAR(max)) AS TreePath
    FROM #tblTable1 AS a
    inner join cte
       ON cte.Employee = a.ReportsTo
    )
```

And now that you have all the nodes/branches, you can select the ones that reflect the proper depth that you want.  (The concat also adds in the final employee to the Tree Path.)
This select also gives you the correct depth of zero for the top node.

```
SELECT
    cte.Employee
    ,cte.TopNode AS ReportsTo
    ,case when cte.ReportsTo is null
             then cte.Depth 
          else cte.Depth + 1
     end AS Depth
    ,case when cte.ReportsTo is null
             then cte.Employee
          else CAST(cte.TreePath + ' -> ' +
               CAST(cte.Employee AS VARCHAR(max)) 
               AS VARCHAR(max)) 
     end AS TreePath
FROM cte
WHERE
   cte.TopNode is not null
   or cte.ReportsTo is null
ORDER BY
   cte.TopNode
   ,cte.Depth;
```

The result set is:

> ```
> Employee  ReportsTo   Depth   TreePath
> a         NULL        0       a
> b         a           1       a -> b
> c         a           2       a -> b -> c
> d         a           3       a -> b -> c -> d
> c         b           1       b -> c
> d         b           2       b -> c -> d
> d         c           1       c -> d
> ```

Comment: is there a possible way of running the recursive query on the letters first and then replacing the letters with names in the TreePath? The names would be stored in a different table with two columns: EmployeeLetter, EmployeeName.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
with cte
    (root
    ,Employee
    ,ReportsTo
    ,depth)
as
    (
    select  ReportsTo root
            ,Employee
            ,ReportsTo
            ,0 as depth
    from    [Table 1] t1

    UNION ALL

    select  b.root
            ,a.Employee
            ,a.ReportsTo
            ,b.depth + 1
    from    cte b
    join [Table 1] a    
            on a.ReportsTo = b.Employee
    )

select  distinct Employee , root ReportsTo,  depth+1 depth
from    cte
where depth = 0 or root is not null --  needn't null as a boss but on 0 level
order by depth;
```